# Filtering out data points from a variable in R

Tags: r

I am new to coding and using R, but I am looking at data from a research project. One of the variables I have contains practice runs before the test, so the variable has "Practice(1)", "Practice(2)", "Test(1)", "Test(2)", and "closing screen". I want to filter out "Practice(1)", "Practice(2)", and "closing screen". How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
newdf<- data[data$variable=="Practice(1)"
             |data$variable=="Practice(2)"
             |data$variable=="closing screen",]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%in%` function to stay with all the elements that match a vector.

```
# Dummy data that may be similar to your original data
df = data.frame(var = rep(c("Practice(1)", "Practice(2)", "Test(1)", "Test(2)", "closing screen"),each = 5),
                var2 = rnorm(25,10,1))

#Create a vector which contains the levels of var that you are interested in
varsIwant <-c("Practice(1)", "Practice(2)", "closing screen")

#Stay only with the rows where its var level matches any of the varsIwant vector
df[df$var %in% varsIwant,]
```